# How to create a bit array in common lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, bitarray

After googling for about an hour, I have to confess, that while I find a lot of documentation about functions operating on bit arrays, I cannot find a single reference on how to actually create a bit array.

Right now, it seems to me that either, some arrays with other element types can be handled as bit arrays OR that one could use `(make-array :element-type (???))` where I could not find any explanation as to what to put where I wrote the "???".

So, while it is probably obvious to anyone else, I have no idea how to create a bit array. I know about how to write a literal bit array - but if I need a bit array with, say 2^16 bits - how would I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right about using `make-array`, just use `'bit` as the element type. Try
`(make-array initial-size :element-type 'bit)`.
The symbol `BIT` names the bit type and could be replaced with any other type specifier to make an array holding objects of that type. In this example `initial-size` is just a variable holding a whole number.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to create a bit vector:

```
> (make-sequence '(vector bit) 10)
#*0000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also a literal syntax using the `#*` reader macro, and notice that the concrete type may differ between using `make-array` and `make-sequence`, though I am not sure if performance may be different depending on that...

Tested with SBCL:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defvar arr (make-array 10 :element-type 'bit :fill-pointer 0))
ARR

CL-USER> (type-of arr)
(VECTOR T 10)

CL-USER> (defvar arr3 (make-sequence '(vector bit) 10))
ARR3

CL-USER> (type-of arr3)
(SIMPLE-BIT-VECTOR 10)

CL-USER> (type-of #*0101010100)
(SIMPLE-BIT-VECTOR 10)
```

Comment: Interesting find! Yet, in my sbcl: `CL-USER> (array-element-type #*11110001010111)
BIT
CL-USER> (array-element-type (make-array 10 :element-type 'bit))
BIT`

Comment: The key difference here is the use of :fill-pointer, which requires the implementation to use an actual vector object instead of simple-array or any of its subtypes. :adjustable is similarly problematic, as I recall, which among other things means that replacement-based array insertion/appending can be faster than side-effecting approaches due to the simple-array optimizations (There's another CL SO question which shows this).

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

- (setq x 10)
- 10
- (setq y (read-from-string (format nil "#*~7,'0b" x)))
- #*0001010
- The 7 is an arbitrary length, which could be set by
- (setq z 8)
- 8
- (setq y (read-from-string (format nil (concatenate 'string "#*~" (write-to-string z) ",'0b") x)))
- #*00001010
- A large bit array may be better handled as an unsigned integer.

Comment: Thanks to pointer tagging, the `most-positive-fixnum` is `CL-USER> (format nil "~B" most-positive-fixnum)
"11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
CL-USER> (length *)
62` 62 bits. Up to that length, your answer is valid.

Comment: Had the inventors of the chess game known about pointer tagging, they would have created a chess board with only 62 squares, so magic bitboards can be implemented efficiently in Common Lisp ;) As they did not, we still have to send our letters of plea to INTEL, so they finally create a 66 bit architecture...

Comment: I think my LISP, gcl, automatically goes to "bignum", so my code can easily do 200 bits.  But I like to print a large number of bits in hexadecimal, which is supported by format for a number, but it does not seem to do that for a bit vector.

Comment: All of those intermediate function calls (`read-from-string`, `concatenate`, `write-to-string`, but especially `format`) make this a pretty expensive way to create a bit vector. -- "_....but it does not seem to do that for a bit vector._" This shouldn't come as a surprise since a `bit-vector` isn't a number.